# Compact metric space: proof $\text{diam}(K)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, compactness

I am to assume that $K$ is a compact metric space.  I must prove that there are two points $x,y$ contained in $K$ such that $d(x,y)=\text{diam}(K)$.

Recall $\text{diam}(K)= \sup \{ d(x,y) \mid x,y \in K \}$.

I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what I need to do to get started on this proof and what it is I need to prove along the way.  I know the definitions, but I'm having trouble applying them to this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The metric $d : (x,y) \mapsto d(x,y)$ is continuous, so by compactness $d$ has a maximum on $K \times K$.