# Show that $f$ has a unique fixed point USING THIS HINT ONLY

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $(X,\ d)$ is a compact metric space and $f:X\to X$ is a continuous function with the property that $$d(f(x),\ f(y))\le\frac{1}{2}d(x,\ y)$$ $\forall x,\ y\in X$.

Show that $f$ has a unique fixed point.

*Hint:* Define $f^1=f$ and $f^{n+1}=f\circ f^n$. Consider the intersection of the sets $A_n=f^n(X)$.

Comment: While this would be using a jackhammer to crack open a walnut, the Banach fixed-point theorem does cover this case. Y. Forman has given a good direct proof.

Comment: @bitesizebo What's the easier way to do this, then?

Comment: There isn't (to my knowledge) an easier proof than Y. Forman's. I just thought it might be interesting to know that this is essentially a subcase of a more powerful theorem known as the Banach fixed point theorem. It deals with when $X$ is just complete rather than compact.

Comment: @bitesizebo if one ignores the hint, there is a very quick proof using compactness

Answer (score 3):

The key point here is that a compact metric space has finite diameter (see, e.g., [Compact metric space: proof $\text{diam}(K)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337650/compact-metric-space-proof-textdiamk?noredirect=1&lq=1)). $A_n$ is a nested sequence of sets (because the range of $f^n$ is contained in the range of $f^{n+1}$) with shrinking diameter approaching zero (because the diameter of $f(S)$ is $\leq \frac12$ the diameter of $S$ for any set $S \subset X$). So its intersection is a single point $p$; since $f(p)$ must also be in the intersection, $p$ is a fixed point.

Answer (score 1):

ignoring the hint, here is the easiest proof: define
$$  g(x) = d(x,f(x)).  $$
This is continuous, the space is compact, so $g$ assumes its minimum at some $x_0.$ **Assume** that $g(x_0) = \delta > 0.$ Then $g(f(x_0)) = d(f(x_0), f(f(x_0)) \leq \frac{1}{2} d(x_0, f(x_0)) = \frac{1}{2} \delta < \delta.$
This **contradicts** the assumption that $\delta \neq 0.$ That is, $g(x_0) = 0$ and $x_0$ is a fixpoint

Comment: How do you see that the minimum is attained at a unique point?

Comment: @Legoman you don't do that directly. Once $x_0$ is a fixpoint, if $y \neq x_0,$ then $d( f(y), x_0 ) < d(y,x_0)$ so $y \neq f(y)$

Comment: I see! Thanks :) +1